# SQL Server: How to check if CLR is enabled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, clr

SQL Server 2008 - What is an easy way to check if clr is enabled?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'clr enabled'
```

Comment: Additional Note : Value will be 1 if enabled, or 0 if disabled.

Comment: This is still valid in SQL 2016.

Answer (score 39):

Check the `config_value` in the results of `sp_configure`

You can enable CLR by running the following:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

[MSDN Article on enabling CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131048.aspx)

[MSDN Article on sp_configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188787.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you should actually configure the option just to check if it's configured! I realize it will say `was 0 now 1`, or similar, but ...

Answer (score 30):

The accepted answer needs a little clarification.  The row will be there if CLR is enabled or disabled.  Value will be 1 if enabled, or 0 if disabled.

I use this script to enable on a server, if the option is disabled:

```
if not exists(
    SELECT value
    FROM sys.configurations
    WHERE name = 'clr enabled'
     and value = 1
)
begin
    exec sp_configure @configname=clr_enabled, @configvalue=1
    reconfigure
end
```

Comment: EXISTS() is slightly faster than NOT EXISTS(). Just a friendly note. ;)

Comment: in this case imho readability trumps performance, which for a single shot dba usage like this would be infinitesimal.

Answer (score 3):

```
select *
from sys.configurations
where name = 'clr enabled'
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct result for me with SQL Server 2017:

```
USE <DATABASE>;
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled' ,1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'clr enabled'   -- make sure it took
GO

USE <DATABASE>
GO

EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
USE <DATABASE>
GO

ALTER DATABASE <DATABASE> SET TRUSTWORTHY ON;
```

From [An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65675](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089112)

Answer (score 2):

This is @Jason's answer but with simplified output

```
SELECT name, CASE WHEN value = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS 'Enabled'
FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'clr enabled'
```

The above returns the following:

```
| name        | Enabled |
-------------------------
| clr enabled | YES     |
```

Tested on SQL Server 2017