# Can not create Database Diagram - Could not obtain information about Windows NT Group/User

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ssms, sql-server-2017

I'm using a Local MS SQL Database, the database was created automatically using entity framework. 
The database is created with out any errors.

However when I use Microsoft Managment studio to try and create a database diagram I get the following error:

[image]

Even when I login as the SA user I still get the same error, any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix this error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845836/could-not-obtain-information-about-windows-nt-group-user

Comment: That link basically says to change the DB owner to sa. Fine. But why does sa need to be owner to create a diagram?  In my case my machine is AzureAD Joined, but not Domain Joined (`dsregcmd /status`)

Comment: No, it says that you must be logged in in your domain.

Answer (score -3):

sql 2019 - Change the owner to sa
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCuCR.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).